# How do I access fingerprint device using PHP and Python?

Tags: php, python, fingerprint

I am to build a simple fingerprint scanner web app using PHP or Python. So how do i access my fingerprint scanner of my laptop for starting the project using PHP or Python ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: access_fingerprint_scanner(). No seriously, how much do you know about PHP, Python or peripherals?

Comment: Do you have an SDK of any form to access your fingerprint scanner? If not then there is no answer to your question. If you do then the answer depends on your SDK and has nothing at all to do with the hardware.

Comment: @str: well i'm not an expert in php or python...but i have done few peripheral interfacing in C...i know it can be done in C or Java...just think about scenario if we can do this in php or python then we can implement biometric identification in a web app itself :)

Comment: Regarding biometrics in a web app... generally web apps run on the server, and your biometric hardware is on the client. Assuming you're asking about PHP/Python because these are common CGI / server side extension languages, you have no way for that server code to reach out to your client's hardware.

Comment: @mah Thanks. Then JavaScript maybe ?

Comment: The problem is a bit larger than deciding a language I think. You most likely need to write a browser plugin using at least some native code (since your fingerprint reader SDK will probably be based on that). You'll also need to manage the UI to direct the user (through JavaScript, perhaps). Then you need to decide what to do with the image... match it on the client, or export to the server. All in all, it's really a rather complex situation. It's not unsolvable, of course, and others (such as Biokey) have solved it... but it's not a small problem to solve.